# How can I save all taxonomy terms automatically?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'am using hook_taxonomy_term_presave to redirect file urls to another link.

In order to see the changes I need to go to : Mysite/taxonomy/term/10/edit and save the page.

I need to do this operation for all taxonmy terms of my website, is there a way to do this automatically whithout editing every page and save it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have drush installed?

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. Yes I have drush installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this to get all my taxonomy terms :

```
function Mymodule_update_7100() {
 $terms = array();
 $v = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('vocab_name');
 $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
 $result = $query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
  ->propertyCondition('vid', $v->vid)
  ->execute();

if (!empty($result['taxonomy_term'])) {
  $terms = entity_load('taxonomy_term', array_keys($result['taxonomy_term']));
}
    foreach($terms as $term){
        taxonomy_term_save($term);
    }
}
```

I hope this will help someone else.
Thank's again @Елин Й.

Answer (score 0):

The best I know from your question is to use the [Views Global Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/global_filter) module.

Using this module you can save you taxonomy term into cookie and get any where in the page and can also redirect and filter the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your modules `.install` file, using [`hook_update_N`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7). The script you need:

```
/**
 * Updates all terms in 'vocabulary_name' vocabulary.
 *
 * Change the update number accordingly if you have previous updates already.
 */
function YOURMODULE_update_7100 {
  $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('vocabulary_name');
  $terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary->vid, 0, NULL, TRUE);
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    taxonomy_term_save($term);
  }
}
```

After that simply run your update script by calling `update.php` or using drush:

> drush updatedb

#### Method 2

If you don't want to use an update script, you can do it using `drush php-eval`, as well. This is a one-line version of the above script:

> drush php-eval '$v = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load("vocabulary_name"); $ts = taxonomy_get_tree($v->vid, 0, NULL, TRUE); foreach ($ts as $t) {taxonomy_term_save($t);}'

Comment: Glad that it helped. I've noticed that I had a typo in the update script, so it wouldn't work as it was.